# Template struct as array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, struct, types

Is it possible to make an array of a struct with template type fields?

```
template<typename T>
struct MyStruct {
    T *pField;
};

MyStruct< ?? > mystruct_arr[] = {
        { pFieldOfType1 },
        { pFieldOfType2 },
};
```

The above obviously doesn't work, but is it possible with other techniques?

I am trying to loop through the array mystruct_arr and call this function on every struct row:

```
template<typename T>
void SetupField(T &pSourceField, ...)
{
    Base *field = ...->findBaseFieldFromDatabase(...);
...
    pSourceField = static_cast<T>(field);
...
}
```

The reason is to try to refactor a very repetitive piece of code where I have to static_cast a long list of different types according to a few different arguments, without making it overly complicated.

Comment: As you only contain a pointer in MyStruct, why not consider using void* instead if you want to achieve this purpose?

Comment: Suppose you somehow managed to declare and initialize `mystruct_arr`. How would you use it?

Comment: Igor's question is key.  Because ypur answer to it determines how to solve your problem.  The declararion you made above has no observable behaviour; an empty file matches those requirements.  Specify *exactly* what you *need*, and a solution can perhaps be found.  Ask for the moon, or vaguely talk about "I was just wondering", and the answer is "no".

Comment: @Yakk true, updated my question to include more what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template is not a `class`, or a `struct`. It can be thought of as a blueprint, or a recipe, for a `class` or a `struct` that gets created when the template gets instantiated.

A template becomes an actual `class` or a `struct` only when it is instantiated, by specifying the required template parameters:

```
MyStruct<int>
```

Now you have an actual, living, breathing `class` here. But a `MyStruct<int>` would be a completely different class than `MyStruct<char>`. Without specifying the template parameters, `MyStruct` is not a class, or a struct, or anything that takes up a single byte of RAM. It's just a template for some `struct` or `class`.

But with template parameters, such as `MySutrct<int>`, this becomes an actual class with fields, and perhaps methods. Now that you have a class you can certainly have an array of these, now:

```
MyStruct<int> mystruct_arr[] = {

};
```

Or you could have a different array of `MyStruct<char>`s:

```
MyStruct<char> mystruct_arr2[] = {

};
```

But you can't have an array that contains both of these for the same, exact, precise reason that you can't have a single array containing a smorgasbord of different types and classes. You can't have an array that contains both `char`s, `int`s, `float`s, pointers, or various classes. An array always contains values of the same type/class. So pick one particular `MyStruct<whatever>`, and make an array out of it, that's all you can do.

But you can also declare another structure, now:

```
struct many_structs {
     MyStruct<int> int_struct;
     MyStruct<char> char_struct;

     // ...
};
```

This sort of starts to look like an array you would like to have. But it's not an array. It's just an ordinary `struct`; and instead of using an array index to access a particular template instance, you would refer to the struct member directly.

You could, with some additional work, specialize `std::get` for your structure, and make this structure look like an array. But now you just realized that you reinvented `std::tuple`, and can simply to do this:

```
std::tuple<MyStruct<int>, MyStruct<char>> mystruct_tuple;
```

Finally, the closest approximation to what you're trying to do is possible only with some additional work, and with a C++ compiler that supports C++17, by declaring an array containing [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)s, or perhaps [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)s. If the array should only contain an a limited enumeration of template instances, `std::variant` gives the most type-safety, and convenience:

```
std::variant<MyStruct<int>, MyStruct<char>> mystruct_arr[]={

};
```

The resulting array contains only these two particular template instances. And with `std::any`, the screws get loosened further but you'll have to do more work to use and access each value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You think you want an array of templates.

What you really want is an array of types you can call a particular template function on.

The first is not possible.  The second is called type erasure in C++.

```
template<class T>
using setup_fptr=void(*)(T &, Foo)
using gen_setup_ptr=void(*)(void*, Foo);

template<class T>
setup_ptr<T> get_setup(){ return SetupField<T>; }
template<class T>
gen_setup_ptr get_gen_setup(){
  return [](void* p, Foo f){ get_setup<T>( *static_cast<T*>(p), f ); };
}
struct can_setup {
  void* ptr=0;
  gen_setup_ptr f=0;

  can_setup(can_setup const&)=default;
  can_setup& operator=(can_setup const&)=default;
  can_setup()=default;
  explicit operator bool() const{return f;}

  template<class T>
  can_setup(T* pt):
    ptr(pt),
    f( get_gen_setup<T>() )
  {}
  void setup( Foo foo ) const {
    f(ptr, foo );
  }
};
```

store an array of `can_setup`.  Loop over them calling `.setup(foo)`.

`Foo` is a placeholder for whatever other args you are using.

This technique is known as type erasure; we forget (erase) everything about `T` except that we can `setup` it.

Comment: It seems like your help would solve my problem, but I'm struggling a bit converting the lambda return [](void* p, Foo f){ get_setup<T>( *static_cast<T*>(p), f ); }; into c++ 98 compatible code. Any ideas?

Comment: @fred `template<class T>void gen_setup(void*p, Foo f){  get_setup<T>( *static_cast<T*>(p), f ); }`